# Disabling device drivers from .cmd script doesn't disable devices from applications

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

My Windows 10 MSI laptop has three cameras:

- EOS Webcam Utility (DSLR driver)
- HD Webcam (built into laptop)
- HD Pro Webcam C920 (Logitech USB camera)

[image]

I wish to disable `EOS Webcam Utility` and `HD Webcam` so the snapshot tool finds the only remaining camera, the Logitech `HD Pro Webcam C920`.

I can disable the drivers as follows.  The icons in device manager show the devices are disabled, and the text in the command prompt tells me it's disabled and re-enabled at the end.  However the snapshot tool still finds the unwanted cameras.

The other option is to find the id # of the Logitech cam and pass that as argument to `CommandCam.exe`.

My `.cmd` file looks like this, after much mangling with strings:

```
@echo off

set "EOSCAM_ID=""root\EOSWebcamSource"""
set "MSICAM1_ID=""USB\VID_5986^&PID_211C^&REV_0301^&MI_00"""
set "MSICAM2_ID=""USB\VID_5986^&PID_211C^&MI_00"""

devcon disable %EOSCAM_ID%
devcon disable %MSICAM1_ID%
devcon disable %MSICAM2_ID%
timeout /T 2 /NOBREAK

For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/: " %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a-%%b-%%c)
set imname=images\image-%mydate%__%mytime%.bmp
CommandCam.exe /delay 2000 /devnum 1 /preview /filename %imname%

devcon enable %EOSCAM_ID%
devcon enable %MSICAM1_ID%
devcon enable %MSICAM2_ID%

python python\convert.py images
explorer images
```

So how do I properly disable the drivers such that `CommandCam.exe` can't find them?  FWIW the Windows camera app also continues to find the EOS camera.  Sometimes, but not always, the laptop camera also remains visible to apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0" 

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f tokens^=*delims^=.^  %%i in ('"%~dp0CommandCam.exe" /devlist 2^>^&1^|findstr [0-9]\.
     ')do <con: echo\%%~i|find "HD Pro Webcam C920" >nul && set "_myCam=%%~i" 
             
for /f %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%\wbem\wmic.exe OS get LocalDateTime^|find "."
     ')do set "_d=%%~i" && <con: call set "_mydate=!_d:~0,4!-!_d:~6,2!-!_d:~4,2!"
     
if %_d:~8,2% leq 11 (set "_mytime=%_d:~8,2%-%_d:~10,2%_AM"
     )else set "_mytime=%_d:~8,2%-%_d:~10,2% PM"

set "_imname=images\image-!_mydate!_!_mytime!.bmp"
     
"%~dp0CommandCam.exe" /delay 2000 /devnum !_myCam:~0,1! /preview /filename "!_imname!"

python python\convert.py images && endlocal && goto :eof
```

---

**1.** Use a `For /F` loop with `CommandCam.exe /devlist` to find and define your desire camera:

```bat
for /f tokens^=*delims^=.^  %%i in ('"%~dp0CommandCam.exe" /devlist 2^>^&1^|findstr [0-9]\.
     ')do <con: echo\%%~i|find "HD Pro Webcam C920" >nul  && set "_myCam=%%~i"
```

**2.** Use `wmic.exe OS get LocalDateTime` to get date/time **[independent of the locale and/or user settings](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2011/02/parsing-dates-in-batch-files-regional-settings-locale)**

```bat
for /f %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%\wbem\wmic.exe OS get LocalDateTime^|find "."
     ')do set "_d=%%~i" && <con: call set "_mydate=!_d:~0,4!-!_d:~6,2!-!_d:~4,2!"
```

**3.** If you don't need string `AM/PM` in `_mytime` variable, just remove `if` condition and add:

```bat
if %_d:~8,2% leq 11 (set "_mytime=%_d:~8,2%-%_d:~10,2%_AM"
   )else set "_mytime=%_d:~8,2%-%_d:~10,2%_PM"

set "_mytime=%_d:~8,2%-%_d:~10,2%"
```

**4.** As the `CommandCam.exe` takes arguments and allows you to define which device to use, instead of removing/disabling rehabilitating/reinstalling the other cameras, try to pass by argument the desired camera:

```bat
"%~dp0CommandCam.exe" /delay 2000 /devnum !_myCam:~0,1! /preview /filename "!_imname!"
```

**5.** An alternative to define the camera string is that you could relax a little with excessive use of escaping `^ "`:

```bat
set "EOSCAM_ID= "" root\EOSWebcamSource "" "
set "MSICAM1_ID= "" USB\VID_5986 ^ &PID_211C^ &REV_0301 ^ &MI_00 "" "
set "MSICAM2_ID= "" USB\VID_5986 ^ &PID_211C ^ &MI_00 "" "

set "_EOSCAM_ID=root\EOSWebcamSource"
set "_MSICAM2_ID=USB\VID_5986&PID_211C&MI_00"
set "_MSICAM1_ID=USB\VID_5986&PID_211C&REV_0301&MI_00"
```

**6.** Some options to enable/disable your cameras:

```bat
for %%i in ("%_EOSCAM_ID%","%_MSICAM2_ID%","%_MSICAM1_ID%"
     )do <con: "%~dp0devcon.exe" disable "%%~i"

for %%i in ("%_EOSCAM_ID%","%_MSICAM2_ID%","%_MSICAM1_ID%"
     )do <con: "%~dp0devcon.exe" enable "%%~i"
```

**7.** Or using the `wmic` console:

```bat
for %%G in ("EOS Webcam Utility","HD Webcam"
)do wmic path Win32_PnPEntity where name='%%~G' call disable

for %%G in ("EOS Webcam Utility","HD Webcam"
)do wmic path Win32_PnPEntity where name='%%~G' call enable
```

---

**Obs.:.** To disable/enable devices you probably need to run with administrator credential/rights

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)
- [`WMIC /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)